# NullPointerException is displayed while starting a static driver using@BeforeClass and getting the driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I am starting the appium server and setting the driver by @BeforeClass and handling driver in another method and calling it from the test cases

```
package setup;

import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import net.bytebuddy.utility.RandomString;

public class Base {
    String deviceIp = "192.148.31.156";

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    public static AndroidDriver driverA;
    static URL appiumURL;
    static DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    @BeforeSuite
    public void startServer() {
        try {
            runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k adb connect " + deviceIp + "");
            runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static AndroidDriver setDriver() {

        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "12.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "192");
        capabilities.setCapability("unlockKey", "934448");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\APK files\\YEO App Android\\app.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");

        try {
            appiumURL = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4733/wd/hub");
            driverA = new AndroidDriver(appiumURL, capabilities);
            // driverA.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, nulls);
            driverA.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return driverA;
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void stopServer() {
        try {
            runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM node.exe");
            runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static AndroidDriver getDriver() {
        // this.setDriver();
        return driverA;
    }

}
```

And Calling the driver as below

```
package testcases;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Resources.RuntimeHandler;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import pageFactories.LaunchScreen;
import pageFactories.MessagesScreen;
import pageFactories.SettingsScreen;
import pageFactories.YEOLockScreen;
import setup.Base;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class TC_LoginToYEO extends Base {   
    LaunchScreen launch = new LaunchScreen(getDriver());
    YEOLockScreen lock = new YEOLockScreen(getDriver());
    SettingsScreen settings = new SettingsScreen(getDriver());
    MessagesScreen ms = new MessagesScreen(getDriver());

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void login_To_YEO() {
        launch.select_Country_Code("India");
        launch.login("891", "3");
    }
}
```

i'm expecting the driver to continue but its failing, Please refer the errors and trace

`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:70)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:39)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy12.click(Unknown Source)
    at pageFactories.LaunchScreen.nav_To_LoginPage(LaunchScreen.java:62)
    at pageFactories.LaunchScreen.select_Country_Code(LaunchScreen.java:67)
    at testcases.TC_LoginToYEO.login_To_YEO(TC_LoginToYEO.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:962)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Anybody provides a solution to this is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar issue. The problem is the following - from the testng official website:
"@BeforeClass: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked."

Which means that basically your class "TC_LoginToYEO" is initialized before the @BeforeClass method is executed; and since the driver has not been created at that moment, and is passed on as null.

A simple workaround would be to do the following:

```
public class TC_LoginToYEO extends Base {   
    LaunchScreen launch;
    YEOLockScreen lock;
    SettingsScreen settings;
    MessagesScreen ms;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void classLevelBeforeMethod(){

    launch = new LaunchScreen(getDriver());
    lock = new YEOLockScreen(getDriver());
    settings = new SettingsScreen(getDriver());
    ms = new MessagesScreen(getDriver());

    }


    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void login_To_YEO() {
        launch.select_Country_Code("India");
        launch.login("891", "3");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!